# How do I divide a cell into multiple cells depending on the quantity?

Tags: excel-formula

I don't understand Excel formulas at all. I think that I have all other columns figured out for what is needed, except I cannot figure out the formulas in Columns N, O, P, Q. When the column L amount is more than 250, I need to split the column L amount in an equal amount in N, O, P, & Q if needed.

i.e., Row **4** would split into **N** & **O**, Row **5** would split into **N**, **O** & **P**, Row **6** wouldn't split, Row **7** would split into **N**, **O**, **P**, & **Q**.

The numbers in Columns I have manually added the amounts that I want it to split into in Columns N, O, P, Q up to the 250 per cell.

[image: Screenshot of Spreadsheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `N4`, formula copied across right to `Q4` and all copied down :

```
=IF(($L4>250)*(COLUMN(A$1)<=ROUNDUP($L4/250,0)),ROUND($L4/ROUNDUP($L4/250,0),0),0)
```

[image]